# What can you use instead of react-native-fast-image?

Tags: react-native, react-image

I am working with Expo and i dont want to use dev client. Anyone got any alternative to react-native-fast-image or a way to implement it without using dev client?

Comment: This question is marked with `react` tags. If you're using react, then how do you plan on avoiding processing on the client-side?

Answer (score 3):

expo-image is a better alternative to react-native-fast-image. It is still new package. Here's link for it's doc https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/image/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it has "Disk and memory caching", among other things, but that's what made fast-image so good. So there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new package and does not have as many features as react-native-fast-image yet but it handles remote images rapidly with disk/memory caching.

https://github.com/xerdnu/react-native-blasted-image

Answer (score -1):

There are bunch of alternatives available instead of react-native-fast-image
.
These are some of them

1. react-native-scroll-lazy
2. @times-components/lazy-load
3. @freakycoder/react-native-progressive-fast-image
4. react-native-progressive-image
5. react-native-just-timeline
6. rn-progressive-image

Try anything from these.